# Difference between ruby StringScanner post_match and rest?

Tags: ruby, tokenize

What is the difference between ruby's `StringScanner#post_match` and `StringScanner#rest`?

```
scanner = StringScanner.new('Say hello to...')
scanner.scan(/\w+/) #=> 'Say'
scanner.scan(/\s+/) #=> ' '
scanner.rest        #=> 'hello to...'
scanner.post_match  #=> 'hello to...'
scanner.rest.class  #=> String
scanner.post_match.class #=> String
```

I don't see a difference. It seems like both return a string containing everything after the match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's difference when there was no match yet.

```
require 'strscan'

scanner = StringScanner.new('Say hello to...')
scanner.rest        # => "Say hello to..."
scanner.post_match  # => nil
```

If there's no match - `post_match` returns nil, naturally (because, you know, there's nothing to read post of).